# Vertx web routing - multiple body handlers

Tags: java, vert.x

I am working on file upload over REST in Vertx. I'm implementing this in existing project so there is already lot of routing definitions. I have problem defining body handler for my upload route. In existing routing definitions is first definition of body handler as follows:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024));
```

This should set this body handler for all incoming requests. And now later in the code I want to define special body handler for uploads:

```
router.post("/upload/path").handler(BodyHandler.create("/upload/dir").setBodyLimit(maxUploadSize));
```

But this does not work. BodyHandler is not "overriden". It only works when I define upload definition first, before the "common" body handler. So this works for me:

```
router.post("/upload/path").handler(BodyHandler.create("/upload/dir").setBodyLimit(maxUploadSize));
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024));
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to define common handler first, and later some routes could define another handler. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "override" handlers. The `BodyHandler` task is to setup the proper handlers in the incomming request and parse the request body. These events are fired just once, so if you add several handlers only the first one to match will he able to handle the events.

You probably don't need to have several handlers has a top level one could parse the request body and populate the form data and file uploads properties in the routing context. So if you want it to behave differently, upload to different locations you can just perform a file move operation.

If you have the need for totally different configurations then you need to specify routes that do not intersect, for example:

```
router.post("/upload/path")
  .handler(BodyHandler.create("/upload/dir").setBodyLimit(maxUploadSize));
router.route("/something/else")
  .handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024));
```

As you can see the 2 routers are different and only 1 will be matched leaving you to have the right upload config.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification. Just seems to be a bit not intuitive since I try to "set" new handler for route and its not actually used or exception thrown. But I understand that only one is used.

Comment: Wow, this answer really saved me!  I upgraded to Vert.x 4.x recently, and started to get the dreaded `IllegalStateException: Request has already been read`.  Can we add some Java docs to `Route.handler(Handler<RoutingContext>)` to give a hint about `BodyHandler.create()`?  It would be helpful for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. I also struggled with this. From my experience vert.x has a route matching algorithm that matches the first possible registered route. This means that if you have

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024));
router.post("/upload/path").handler(BodyHandler.create("/upload/dir").setBodyLimit(maxUploadSize));
```

then it will match with`router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024));` first and will throw an error if you try to run the request through another body handler.

In the case of:

```
router.post("/upload/path").handler(BodyHandler.create("/upload/dir").setBodyLimit(maxUploadSize));
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024));
```

It will match your body handler first and ignore the other one since it already matched a part of the path.

You could add an if clause to the

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024));
```

where on `"/upload/path"` you just call `next()` instead of the body handler but I would not call this a good solution.