# How to fix 'Request has already been read' error in Vert.x

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm setting up a api gateway. I want to verrify Authorization token before request BE service. I got IllegalStateException: Request has already been read. Please help.

I uploaded the test project code to GitHub. 
https://github.com/EddyPan/test-demo

```
router.route().path("/user/admin").method(HttpMethod.POST)
        .handler(rct -> {

            HttpServerRequest request = rct.request().setExpectMultipart(true);

            MultiMap headers = request.headers();

            JsonObject param = new JsonObject().put("requestUrl", "http://localhost:18080/authorize")
                    .put("httpMethod", "POST");

            webClient.postAbs("http://localhost:18080/authorize")
                    .timeout(6000)
                    .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .putHeader("Authorization", headers.get("Authorization"))
                    .as(BodyCodec.jsonObject())
                    .sendJsonObject(param, ar -> authHandler(rct, ar));

        });
```

exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.checkEnded(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:599)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.setExpectMultipart(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:431)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.HttpServerRequestWrapper.setExpectMultipart(HttpServerRequestWrapper.java:208)
    at com.demo.HttpServerVerticle.lambda$start$8(HttpServerVerticle.java:62)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:232)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:121)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:134)
    at com.demo.HttpServerVerticle.authHandler(HttpServerVerticle.java:132)
    at com.demo.HttpServerVerticle.lambda$null$0(HttpServerVerticle.java:53)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.handleDispatchResponse(HttpContext.java:285)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.execute(HttpContext.java:272)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.next(HttpContext.java:250)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.predicate.PredicateInterceptor.handle(PredicateInterceptor.java:69)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.predicate.PredicateInterceptor.handle(PredicateInterceptor.java:32)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.next(HttpContext.java:247)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.fire(HttpContext.java:257)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.dispatchResponse(HttpContext.java:218)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.lambda$null$2(HttpContext.java:341)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:320)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: This will also work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47591213/257299

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue. Before call auth api I pause the original request, and resume buffer processing when the authorize finished.

```
router.route().path("/user/admin").method(HttpMethod.POST)
        .handler(rct -> {

            HttpServerRequest request = rct.request().setExpectMultipart(true);

            request.pause(); // Here is to pasue the origin request.

            MultiMap headers = request.headers();

            JsonObject param = new JsonObject().put("requestUrl", "http://localhost:18080/authorize")
                    .put("httpMethod", "POST");

            webClient.postAbs("http://localhost:18080/authorize")
                    .timeout(6000)
                    .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .putHeader("Authorization", headers.get("Authorization"))
                    .as(BodyCodec.jsonObject())
                    .sendJsonObject(param, ar -> authHandler(rct, ar));

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Two reasons you might end up with this error:**

## A) async `Handler` before `BodyHandler`

As stated in the Vert.X [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/3.9.2/vertx-web/java/#_request_body_handling) for `BodyHandler`:

> The usage of this handler requires that it is **installed as soon as possible** in the router since it needs to install handlers to consume the HTTP request body and this must be done **before executing any async call**.

### Fix 1: Change the order:

```
router.post(endpoint)
   .consumes(contentType)
   .handler(bodyHandler)  <<<<<<<<< first this
   .handler(authHandler) <<<<<<<<  then this async handler;
```

### Fix 2: pause/resume request delivery:

See Vert.X [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/3.9.2/vertx-web/java/#_request_body_handling):

> If an **async call is required before**, the HttpServerRequest should be **paused and then resumed** so that the request events are not delivered until the body handler is ready to process them.

```
router.post(endpoint)
   .consumes(contentType)
   .handler(authHandler)
   .handler(bodyHandler);
```

```
BodyHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
  @Override
  public void handle(final RoutingContext ctx) {

     // pause request delivery
     ctx.request().pause();

     asyncCall(r -> {
        // e.g. check authorization or database here

        // resume request delivery
        ctx.request.resume();

        // call the next handler
        ctx.next();
     }
  }
}
```

## B) Multiple `request.body()` calls

Suppost you use the Vert.X `BodyHandler` and have a custom handler installed after it:

```
router.post(endpoint)
   .consumes(contentType)
   .handler(BodyHandler.create())
   .handler(customHandler);
```

Your custom handler **must not call `request.body()`!** or else you get

```
403: body has already been read
```

### Fix: Use `ctx.getBody()`

Use `ctx.getBody[/asJson/asString]()` to get the body already read by the `BodyHandler`:

```
CustomHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
    @Override
    public void handleAuthorizedRequest(RoutingContext ctx) {
        final var body = ctx.getBodyAsJson();

        // instead of: ctx.request().body();
        ...
    }
}
```